# Inject Application Scoped class to others

Tags: java, cdi

I am trying to inject an Application Scope class to another. It work fine at Servlets, Listeners, Filters and Rest API, but not in POJO, because in the last one I get a reference equal to null, I mean the POJO (class Extra) doesn't use the same instance that other. The idea is that the classes MyServlet.java and Extra.java use the same instance of the class Person.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Person implements Serializable{
    String name;
    int edad;
    
    public Person() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    Person(String name, int edad){
        this.name = name;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}

@WebServlet("/hola")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Extra ex = new Extra(null);
        PrintWriter wr = resp.getWriter();
        wr.print("Hola:"+ex.saludar());
    }
}

@WebServlet("/mundo")
public class MySecond extends HttpServlet{
    
    @Inject
    Person p;
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter wr = resp.getWriter();
        if (p == null) {
            p = new Person();
            p.setName("Second");
        }
        wr.print("Mundo: "+ p.getName());
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Extra implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    Person p;
    
    @Inject
    public Extra(Person p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
    
    public String saludar() {
        if (p == null) {
            p = new Person();
            p.setName("Extra");
        }else
            p.setName("No nulo");
        return p.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `Extra ex = new Extra(null);` to blame?

Comment: Exactly the case, you need to let CDI create the instance; avoid initializing the instance yourself. So just `@Inject` it into the class where you intend to use it or use dynamic resolution via `CDI.current().select(Extra.class).get()`

Comment: CDI.current().select(Extra.class).get() works for me. Thank you both for your help.